# Angular 9 Converting circular structure to JSON error

Tags: angular, angular9

**Hi

> in my post request im sending rootClasses as a json object and dataSource of Angular material table data.

Igot This error:**

```
Error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TakeUntilSubscriber'
    |     property '_parentOrParents' -> object with constructor 'Subscriber'
    |     property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    --- index 0 closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at HttpRequest.serializeBody (http.js:1008)
    at Observable._subscribe (http.js:2408)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
    at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:9)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (mergeMap.js:59)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:53)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:36)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
```

**And my function is like this:**

```
 docLayoutSave(){
  this._fuseSplashScreenService.show();
  this.http.post(this.baseUrl+this.appName+'/saveDijiLayoutTableNew',{
     rootClasses:this.rootClasses,
     diji_LayoutTableList: this.dataSource
  }
   ,  this.header.headerPOST()
  )
  .subscribe( (datatable:any)=>{
  this.dataSource=datatable;
  this._fuseSplashScreenService.hide();
  // window.location.reload();
  }
  , error => {
    this._fuseSplashScreenService.hide();
    if (error.status==401) {
      Swal.fire('Oops...', 'Something went wrong!<br/> Your session is down :(', 'error').then(()=>{
        this.router.navigate(['/pages/auth/login-2'])
      });
    }
    console.log('Error', error);
  });
      
}
```

How can i solve this error.

Comment: `this.rootClasses` is probably an observable, not an actual value

Comment: can you show us more about this.rootClasses ?

Comment: Thank you for everybody. I solve the problem. I replace the 'dataSource' with 'dataSource.data' then error is gone.